# переменная принимает предыдущее значение

Tags: cmd, bat

Пишу скрипт,который бы принимал первым параметром путь к папке и копировал ее содержимое в другую,заданную потом.Есть командные символы для первого параметра, это "/?" по которому выводится краткая информация о задаче,проверка на существование и собственно часть кода,где разбирается путь,если он существует и введен правильно.Если первый параметр точка,то работаем с текущей папкой.

```
@echo off

setlocal
set flag=false

if "%1" EQU "" (
    set flag=true

    echo Не задан основной параметр. Введите /? для справки
    )

if "%1" EQU "/?" (
    set flag=true
    echo командный файл копирования файлов заданного типа с помощью команды copy_   из одной папки в другую. 
    echo В качестве первого обязательного параметра должно быть задано имя исходной папки 
    echo для текущей папки задается символ ".". Вторым необязательным параметром является тип файла
    echo image - для файлов изображений с расширениями .bmp , .gif, .jpg и .png
    echo prog - для программных файлов с расширениями .com и .exe
    echo text - для текстовых файлов с расширениями .doc и .txt
    echo all - для всех файлов.
    echo Если второй параметр не задан, для него предполагается значение all. 
    echo В командном файле выдается запрос на ввод имени папки, в которую будут копироваться файлы
    echo для текущей папки задается символ "." Имена исходной папки и папки, в которую будет производиться копирование
    echo не должны совпадать. Если папка с заданным именем не существует, она создается с помощью команды mkdir.
    echo Для значений параметров image, prog или text должно быть выведено общее количество 
    echo скопированных файлов соответствующего типа изображений, программных или текстовых
    )



 if "%1" NEQ "." (
    echo "%flag%"
    if "%flag%" EQU "false" (
        if exist "%1" (
            echo Путь существует и не равен командным символам
        )else (
            echo Путь не существует
            )
        )
)else (
    echo Текущий путь %cd%
    set/p namefolder="Введите полное имя дериктории для копирования"
    echo %namefolder%
    if exist "%namefolder%" (
        echo Путь существует
    )else (
        echo Пути не существует
        )

)

endlocal
```

У меня странно работает переменная вот тут `set/p namefolder="Введите полное имя дериктории для копирования"`, если первый аргумент точка.  Когда вызываю bat в первый раз, ввожу строку,например "www", то значение namefolder пустое, а если вызываю второй раз,то какую бы строку не ввел,переменная принимает предыдущее значение - "www". И так по кругу,в нее почему то записывается не текущее значение,которое я ввел в консоль, а значение,полученное на предыдущей итерации вызова. Совсем не понимаю,почему так это работает(.Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: `EnableDelayedExpansion`?

Comment: @Akina,можно поподробней,пожалуйста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вложенные `if` - зло, еще большее зло - сами командные сценарии, так как уже давным-давно существуют более функциональные средства вроде `PowerShell` или на худой конец `WSH`. Но раз уж пошла такая пьянка, то стоит сделать еще несколько замечаний.
Отказ от процедурного стиля в данном случае превращает код в "портянку". Во-вторых, стоит отметить: есть одно общее условие, при котором должны копироваться все файлы, а именно `а) при отсутствии второго аргумента, передаваемого командному сценарию` и `б) при указании all`. Учитывая все это, код можно представить так:

```
@echo off
  setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "argc=0" % rem : счетчик аргументов сценария
    for %%i in (%*) do set "argv.!argc!=%%~i" && set /a "argc+=1"
    rem условия вывода справки или выхода за пределы допустимого количества аргументов
    if "!argv.0!" equ "/?" goto:man
    if !argc! lss 1 goto:man
    if !argc! gtr 2 goto:man
    rem если все условия соблюдены, вызываем процедуру копирования файлов
    if !argc! equ 1 call:copyFiles
    if !argc! equ 2 call:copyFiles !argv.1!
  endlocal
exit /b

:man
  echo:Собственно, здесь помещается справочное руководство.
exit /b

:copyFiles
  if not exist "!argv.0!\*" echo:Неправильный путь.&goto:eof
  set /p "dest=Укажите папку назначения: "
  if "!argv.0!" equ "!dest!" echo:Невозможно копировать путь в самого себя.&goto:eof
  if "%~1" equ "" xcopy "!argv.0!" "!dest!" /i>nul
  if /i "%~1" equ "all" xcopy "!argv.0!" "!dest!" /i>nul
  rem прочие условия
  set "image=.BMP;.GIF;.JPG;.PNG"
  set "prog=.COM;.EXE"
  set "text=.DOC;.TXT"
  for %%i in (image prog text) do (
    if /i "%~1" equ "%%~i" set "found=true"
  )
  if not defined found echo:Непредусмотренный тип данных.&goto:eof
  for %%i in ("!%~1:;=";"!") do xcopy "!argv.0!\*%%~i" "!dest!" /i 2>nul >nul
exit /b
```

Comment: Cпасибо большое за код,но я почти ничего не понимаю) Что за argv, как работает присваивание set "argc=0" %. Вот этот цикл     for %%i in (%*) do set "argv.!argc!=%%~i" && set /a "argc+=1"
и переменные,заключенные в ! !. Если не сложно,распишите пожалуйста поподробнее.Спасибо